# Pdf of sum of two uniform random variables on $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent RVs and uniformly distributed on $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$, what is the pdf of $X+Y$? Everything I can find is on the interval $[0,1]$ and I don't know how to choose the integration limits for this non generic case.

Answer (score 0):

We must find the p.d.f. of $X$, $Y$, and joint p.d.f. of $X$ and $Y$ as below.
\begin{align*}
f_X(x)=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{2}-(-\frac{1}{2})}=1 \text{, for } -\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2} \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise.}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
f_Y(y)=\dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{2}-(-\frac{1}{2})}=1 \text{, for } -\frac{1}{2}\leq y\leq \frac{1}{2} \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise.}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f(x)f(y)=1\cdot 1=1 \text{, for } -\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}\leq y\leq \frac{1}{2} \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise.}
\end{align*}

Let $U=X+Y$ and $V=X$.

We can use transformation method to get p.d.f. of $X+Y$.

We find the inverse of transformation, as below.

$X=V$ and $Y=U-X=U-V$.

We have a new domain of $U$ and $V$, i.e.
$-\dfrac{1}{2}\leq V\leq \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $-\dfrac{1}{2}\leq U-V\leq \dfrac{1}{2}$

[image]

We find the jacobian as below.

\begin{align*}
\vert J\vert &= 
\begin{vmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial X}{\partial U}&\dfrac{\partial X}{\partial V}\\
\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial U}&\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial V}\\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
0&1\\
1&-1\\
\end{vmatrix}
=\vert-1\vert
=1.
\end{align*}

Now, we have the joint probability of $U$ and $V$ as below

\begin{align*}
f_{U,V}(u,v)&=f_{X,Y}(x,y)\cdot \vert J\vert\\
&= f_{X,Y}(v,u-v) \cdot 1\\
&= 1.
\end{align*}

for $-\dfrac{1}{2}\leq V\leq \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $-\dfrac{1}{2}\leq U-V\leq \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $0$ otherwise.

To find the p.d.f. of $X+Y$, we find the marginal pdf of $U$ from the joint p.d.f. $f_{U,V}(u,v)$. We have p.d.f. of $U=X+Y$ as below

\begin{align*}
f_{U}(u)&=\int\limits_{u-\frac{1}{2}}^{u+\frac{1}{2}} 1 dv\\
&=\left[v\right]_{u-\frac{1}{2}}^{u+\frac{1}{2}}\\
&= \left(u+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\left(u-\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=1
\end{align*}

for $-\dfrac{1}{2}\leq U \leq \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: But U=X+Y should have range -1 to 1 right?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}
\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2} < z - x < {1 \over 2}}\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}
\bracks{z - {1 \over 2} < x < z + {1 \over 2}}
\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2} < z + {1 \over 2} < {1 \over 2}}
\int_{-1/2}^{z + 1/2}\dd x
\\[2mm] + &\ 
\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2} < z - {1 \over 2} < {1 \over 2}}
\int_{z - 1/2}^{1/2}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{-1 < z < 0}\pars{z + 1}
 +
\bracks{0 < z < 1}\pars{1 - z}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\large\bracks{\vphantom{A^{A^{A}}}
\verts{z} < 1}
\pars{\vphantom{A^{A}}1 - \verts{z}}} \\ &
\end{align}
[image]

Comment: thank you very much, i followed your thought and got the right answer! :)